# "undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()" while compiling a hello world in netbeans

Tags: compiling, netbeans, g++

I am new to ubuntu and I want to code in C++.
I intalled `g++` through software manager and after I installed netbeans to have a nice IDE to code in C++.
Then I write this simple code:

```c
#include <iostream>
//using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char**argv) {
    // Prints welcome message...
    std:: cout << "Welcome ..." << std::endl;

    // Prints arguments...
    if (argc > 1) {
        std::cout << std::endl << "Arguments:" << std::endl;
        for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
            std::cout << i << ": " << argv[i] << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I built the code I got this error:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:74: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
```

This meaning that isn't my code in error bu It seems that iostream refer something that is unknown.

Now, my question is: how I can check if gcc and g++ are installed correctly? 
And, if it is installed well, why g++ doesn't compile?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install g++-multilib` This should solve your problem.

Comment: error is still present , I think it depends by netbeans IDE .I am going to close this question

Comment: Can you try to compile with g++ from the terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is very strange. You need open "Project Properties" window and change 
>   Build|Linker|Tool from gcc to g++

Source: http://forums.netbeans.org/post-51209.html

p.s. I have no probs compiling code with g++, while I get same kind of errors trying with gcc.